# how to make a swipe between images from a grid view?

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, android-viewpager, custom-adapter

what do i have is many tabs between fragments .. each fragment has grid view and each time we press an image in the grid view it should be displayed full screen in a new activity .. and i want to add swipe functionality in this full screen image so the user can swipe left and right between other images in the grid view ... but i keep see an error on the full screen activity and log gave NULL POINTER EXCEPTION !!! please help ..

first of all here is the code for one of the fragments class :

```
public class KitchenBlinds extends Fragment {
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.kit_1, R.drawable.kit_2,
            R.drawable.kit_3, R.drawable.kit_4,
            R.drawable.kit_5, R.drawable.kit_6,
            R.drawable.kit_7, R.drawable.kit_8,
            R.drawable.kit_9, R.drawable.kit_10,
            R.drawable.kit_11, R.drawable.kit_12,
            R.drawable.kit_13, R.drawable.kit_14,
            R.drawable.kit_15
    };
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_kitchen_blinds, container, false);

    GridView gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
      try{
        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), mThumbIds)); 
      } catch (OutOfMemoryError E) { 
        E.printStackTrace();
    }


        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FullImageActivity2.class);
                // passing array index
                 i.putExtra("id", mThumbIds[position]);

                    Log.d("ID", "" + mThumbIds[position]);
                     startActivity(i);
            }   
        });


    return view;    
}


}
```

and then here is the code of the image adapter for the grid view class :

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;


        // Keep all Images in array
        public Integer[] mThumbIds = {};


        public ImageAdapter(Context c,Integer[] mThumbIds2){
            mContext = c;
            this.mThumbIds=mThumbIds2;
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThumbIds[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.edit_border);
            imageView.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

            return imageView;
        }
    }
```

and here is the code for the Image Pager Adapter :

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter  extends PagerAdapter{
    private List<ImageView> images;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(List<ImageView> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = images.get(position);
        container.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView(images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return view == o;
    }
}
```

and finally here is the code of the full screen activity that it crash on it each time i select the image :

```
 public class FullImageActivity2 extends Activity {


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image_activity2);
     // Loop through the ids to create a list of full screen image views
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        for (int i = 0; i < imageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[i]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            images.add(imageView);
        }

        // Finally create the adapter
        ImagePagerAdapter imagePagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(imagePagerAdapter);

        // Set the ViewPager to point to the selected image from the previous activity
        // Selected image id
        int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
    }
```

and i keep see an error on this line :

```
  ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
```

because i configure my constructor in the image adapter to take two parameter which work fine , but i don't know how to pass it here !!! 
please help !! and thx in advance  ...

Comment: try getIntent().getIntExtra()

Comment: it wont work because its an integer Array .. also i am not sure that this is the problem :(

Comment: Are you sending integer array to another activity??

Comment: i tried to do it and i receive it but it give me the same error .. null pointer exception :( .. why?

Comment: OK. Now do one thing. Instead of putting drawable integer. Put position itself. Then access same drawable by making your drawable array in the  FullImageActivity2 by making it static  in KitchenBlinds fragment

Answer (score 1):

well .. i fix the problem by sending the array in the kitchen blinds activity like this :

```
i.putExtra("array", mThumbIds);
```

then i receive it like this and add it to the constructor :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Object[] s = (Object[]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("array");
Integer[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(s, s.length, Integer[].class);
```

and add it to the constructor :

```
ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, newArray);
```